# How to download picture and convert to base64 correctly in Dart?

Tags: dart

I'm in struggle with downloading a picture and then showing it on a page. Printed base64-encoded string looks wrong; it's not identical with e.g. http://www.freeformatter.com/base64-encoder.html result.

This is my code:

```
HttpRequest.request(_url).then((HttpRequest response) {
    String contentType = response.getResponseHeader('Content-Type');

    if (_supportedContentType(contentType)) {
        List bytes = new Utf8Encoder().convert(response.responseText);
        String header = 'data:$contentType;base64,';
        String base64 = CryptoUtils.bytesToBase64(bytes);
        String image = "${header}${base64}";

        me.avatar = image;
        print(image);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem? What output do you expect from `print(image)`?

Comment: Output starts with `data:image/png;base64,77+977+977+977+9ABBKRklGAAEBAQBgAGAAAO+/ve+/vQBDAAYEB` but it should start with `data:image/png;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD/2wBDAAY`. Just to be complete, here's the file url: http://37.139.24.217/images/3b4130fa05294cd2af0624b8826c4425_1406120258.png

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you set the responseType you get binary data

```dart
import 'dart:html' show HttpRequest;
import 'dart:convert' show base64;
import 'dart:typed_data' show Uint8List, ByteBuffer;

main() {
  HttpRequest
      .request("Zacharie_Noterman_-_Monkey_business.jpg",
          responseType: "arraybuffer")
      .then((HttpRequest response) {
    String contentType = response.getResponseHeader('Content-Type');

    var list = new Uint8List.view((response.response as ByteBuffer));

    String header = 'data:$contentType;base64,';
    String base64 = base64.encode(list);
    String image = "${header}${base64}";

    //  me.avatar = image;
    print(image);
    //}
  });
}
```

result:

> data:image/png;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD....

Comment: I have Dart-sdk 1.5.3 and there's no asUint8List() method. Although in documentation it exists.

Comment: I guess there are other options to get a `List<int>` from `ByteBuffer`. I'll try to find one but it might take a while.

Comment: I simplified the previous solution a bit and added another one but I can't tell if this one works in 1.5.3.

Comment: how to do this in flutter ?

Comment: @ahmedkhattab I'd suggest to create a new question for Flutter with more details about your use case.

Comment: here's the question :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58527881/how-to-download-picture-and-convert-to-base64-correctly-in-flutter