# Display selected image in Flutter Web

Tags: image, file, show, flutter-web

Since flutter web is in tech preview, none of the plugins are working.

I have a task to show image, which we select.
I have following picker

```
_startFilePicker() async {
InputElement uploadInput = FileUploadInputElement();
uploadInput.multiple = true;
uploadInput.click();

uploadInput.onChange.listen((e) {
  // read file content as dataURL
  final files = uploadInput.files;
  if (files.length == 1) {
    final file = files[0];
    final reader = FileReader();

    reader.onLoadEnd.listen((e) {
      _handleResult(reader.result);
          });
          reader.readAsDataUrl(file);
        }
      });
      }

        void _handleResult(Object result) {
          setState(() {
            images.add(result);
          });
        }
```

`result` gives me output 
`data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRg....`

How can I display this output in Image Widget?

I tried using `Image.memory(base64Decode(file))`. But file could't be decoded. I suspect because it's not raw base64.

How could I convert this output to visible image? And how to deal with multiple images too?

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In you base64 string, exclude "data:image/jpeg;base64," and only keep "/9j/4AAQSkZJRg..."

Paste your base64 string to online image converter  https://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter, to make sure your base64 string is correct

```
_base64 = "/9j/4AAQSkZJRg...";
```

decode with

```
Uint8List bytes = base64Decode(_base64);
```

and show image with

```
Image.memory(bytes);
```

you can also reference this [How to convert BASE64 string into Image with Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46145472/how-to-convert-base64-string-into-image-with-flutter)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Yes I took inspiration from this topic :) Is there a way to nicely extract base64 string or it's done only manually?

Comment: please reference this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24935653/how-to-download-picture-and-convert-to-base64-correctly-in-dart

Comment: You could use the **RegExp** class from dart:core ( https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.5.0/dart-core/RegExp-class.html )  to remove the header automatically, not manually.

Comment: To extract base64 string I simply take the substring starting from the comma like this: 
String _base64 = result.toString().split(',')[1];